# usability web sites

Tags: css

Where to find website that i could do a report on that needs some usability. I have been looking and dont know where to look at.. Thanks

Comment: I don´t understand your question...

Comment: I have to do a report on a website. I have to find a website that can use usability in it but i dont know where to look for one at?

Comment: Really wow so this project is going to be hard

Comment: Are you looking for links to read about usability? I don't really get it.

Comment: Try to use more than 2 sentences in the questions. It will help us to get what you are looking for.Laconic phrases are not always good, especially  in a case when English is not you first language.

Comment: StackOverflow is a website targeted at **professional software developers**.  If you are not sure about what StackOverflow is or how to behave here, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Your question was closed because it is unanswerable in any reasonable manner as well as being off topic.  If you wish to get good answers, you **must** ask good questions.  I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are performing usability testing of a website you can probably use most any website. You should probably specify criteria on how the website is supposed to be used and then test to see if those criteria are being met. There are several ways of doing this which may be outlined in your report rubric.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find bad websites?

Perhaps put this into your favorite search engine: `best and worst of the web`.

You will see "awards" for the worst of the web and also see some sites to help keep your site off the list.